# What is limitToList="true" equivalent attribute in primefaces?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, richfaces, jsf-2.2

I know that attribute `limitToList="true"` in richfaces 3.5 or `limitRender="true"` in richfaces 4.x allows to dismiss the behavior of the "ajaxRendered" attribute.

Now I'm looking for the equivalent attribute in primefaces 3.5 to dismiss the behaviour of autoUpdate="true", because I don't want to update my p:outputPanel with `autoUpdate="true"` on every ajax call.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: @jinxed Thanks for your effort to make the question more readable. I should have done that. Will remember this for sure from next post .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's none.

You can however do it from the other side on. Just make `autoUpdate` itself conditional. Basically:

```
autoUpdate="#{evaluate true only if you actually need auto update}"
```

You could check for request parameters, pressed buttons or bean properties here the usual way.

Comment: Thanks BalusC. I could do that as you suggested but was looking for an attribute like in rich faces. Anyways it is not that hard to implement what you have suggested.

Comment: As answered, there's none. Create issue ticket at PrimeFaces guys if you really want to see an equivalent in PrimeFaces.

Comment: hmm yeah. Learnt and learning a lot from your answers in this site. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure will post this issue there.

Comment: This issue already some one posted in primefaces community. here is the link http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=13650

Comment: In primefaces 4.X they have added an attribute ignoreAutoUpdate which is equivalent of limitToList in richfaces. This attribute is available on various components like p:ajax, p:commandbutton/link and p:poll  and p:remoteCommand.

Answer (score 2):

Just answering my question with a thought that it may help others.

In primefaces 4.X there is an attribute `ignoreAutoUpdate` which is equivalent of `limitToList` or `limitRender` in richfaces. This attribute is available on various components like p:ajax, p:commandButton p:commandLink and p:poll and p:remoteCommand.